# How to use a relative URL in JavaScript after an HTTP 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, laravel

My application loads a page and then uses AJAX to fetch data.

Some of the AJAX URLs are in a different directory (controller name) to the page being loaded.

I prefer to use URLs that are relative to the current page ("../ajax) rather than the server root (/ajax) because my application might be installed and run from a subdirectory on the server.

AJAX URLs relative to the current page work, but **not** after the page is reached via a 302 redirect (when the URL seems to be relative to the requested page, not the redirected page).

Why? What's the best way to do this?

**Update:** the reason for the 302 redirect is me using Laravel's Redirect::to() method to redirect the user from home/ to home/overview/.

Comment: Its always best to define a base-path which is your application root  and define all other URLs relative to base-path.

Comment: Consider detecting the base path in PHP and outputting that to javascript (perhaps as a JS variable) you can use to prepend to any ajax URL called.